# How i can get the current PublishingSite & PublishingWeb from SPItemEventProperties inside my Event Recevier

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, farm-solution, ssom

I have an publishing site collection  using the enterprise wiki site collection template inside my sharepoint server 2013. And inside the root site of my site collection i added a custom list named "customers", and i added an event receiver which will get fired when a new item is added inside the customers list. the event receiver will create 2 wiki pages as follow:-

```
 public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);

            if (properties.List.Title.ToLower() == "customers")
            {
                PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(properties.Site);
                SPContentType ctype = pSite.ContentTypes["Enterprise Wiki Page"];
                PageLayoutCollection pageLayouts = pSite.GetPageLayouts(ctype, true);
                PageLayout pageLayout = pageLayouts["EnterpriseWiki.aspx"];
                PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(properties.Web);

                ///First page
                PublishingPageCollection pPages = pWeb.GetPublishingPages();
                PublishingPage pPage1 = pPages.Add(properties.ListItem.Title + " - About Customer.aspx", pageLayout);
                SPListItem newpage1 = pPage1.ListItem;
                newpage1["Title"] = properties.ListItem.Title+" - About Customer.aspx";//"Page added programmatically";
                newpage1["PublishingPageContent"] = "<a href='/kb/CustomerServiceKB/Pages/" + properties.ListItem.Title + " - Main.aspx" + @"'>Back To Main Page</a> ";                           

                ///second Page
                PublishingPage pPage = pPages.Add(properties.ListItem.Title + " - Main.aspx", pageLayout);
                SPListItem newpage = pPage.ListItem;
                newpage["Title"] = properties.ListItem.Title + " - Main.aspx";//"Page added programmatically";
                newpage["PublishingPageContent"] = 
                @"<table class='ms-rteTable-default' cellspacing='0' style='width: 65%; height: 803px; text-align: left;'>   //code goes here";
                newpage.Update();
                newpage1.Update();

            }
        }


    }
}
```

now currently i test the above event receiver and it is working well. but as i know that based on MSDN recommendation it is not recommended to create new instances of `SPSite` & `SPWeb` inside event receiver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee724407(v=office.14).aspx .

now in my above event receiver i am not sure about these 2 points:-

1) inside these 2 lines of code, am i violating the MSDN recommendations?? :-

```
PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(properties.Site);
PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(properties.Web);
```

since i am creating new instances of the `PublishingSite` & `PublishingWeb`?

2) now i try to do something as follow, to try to reference the current `PublishingSite` directly from the `SPItemEventProperties` :-

```
 PublishingSite pSite = properties.Site;
```

instead of

```
PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(properties.Site);
```

but i got this error:-

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite' to
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite'

so can anyone adivce on my above two points,, so i can make my event receiver compatible with the MSDN recommendation of not creating new instances of `SPSite` & `SPWeb` inside the event receivers??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR;
1) No, you don't violate MSDN recommendations.
2) No need as per 1)

When you call `new PublishingSite(properties.Site);`, you don't create new `SPSite` or `SPWeb` objects. These 2 objects are "dangerous" because they hold the connections to the DB. However, `PublishingSite` is only a "business wrapper" arround `SPSite`: i.e. it uses `SPSite` to present a "publishing" API by requesting the underlying `SPSite` access to the data.
So, no worries here.

As per your second question:

a. It's now irrelevant :)

b. It fails because `PublishingSite` and `SPSite` are 2 different objects in a C#/.NET sense: they're not related and `PublishingSite` does not inherit from `SPSite`. The only relation they have is `PublishingSite` encapsulating an `SPSite` object.

Comment: thanks for the reply... just to make sure i got ur point correctly .. so when i do something as follow `PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(properties.Site);` & `PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(properties.Web);` then i am still referencing the properties.Site & properties.Web ? so i am inline with the MSDN recommendations ?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.